# Add a React-native Modal with ratings shown from 1-10

Tags: android, react-native, modal-dialog

I would like to add a react-native based alert/modal that asks user to rate from 1-10, (or provide 10 stars). I haven't been able to find right solution anywhere. Please let me know if you can offer help.

This is for an android app

I tried this library:
https://github.com/WrathChaos/react-native-review-modal/tree/master

I couldn't build an app based on this library.

This is another link I tried:
https://reactnativeexample.com/review-modal-with-dynamic-rate-system-and-comment-feature-for-react-native/

I couldn't install with this either

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

you can create your own custom modal and design the UI .
you can use this package to get ratings from user https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ratings.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).